# How to access an uploaded file in the browser in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

I can successfully upload files to the /storage/app folder but now I'm wondering how I can view these (image) files in the browser.

I've setup a symlink /public/storage that points to /storage/app

I'm trying to access the file through http://my-local-domain/storage/myphoto.jpg but it's giving me a NotFoundHttpException.

I know this works in Laravel, but not sure how to get this working in Lumen. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. My symlink was incorrect. 
I executed this command (my current path was the root of my application):

```
ln -s storage/app public/storage
```

This should be (complete paths):

```
ln -s /var/www/storage/app /var/www/public/storage
```